# Importing LandXML data to QGIS 3.22.3

Tags: qgis, xml, autocad, 3d-model, traffic

I am fairly new to QGIS and working in the Environmental Impact field as a noise specialist. We use a noise modelling software called CadnaA which is powerful, but not very user-friendly. To get around this, I am trying to build as much of the model in QGIS as possible and then export it to the software.

Our latest project is a study on road traffic noise for a proposed highway extension and the civil engineers have given me the attached .xml files of the road layout.

I have installed the LandXml plugin and run the import ticking the boxes as follows:

[image]

I have also tried it with ticking all three boxes. When it is done importing, I don't see any error message, the layer is incorporated into the layers panel, but nothing appears. Upon looking into the attribute folder, it shows no features.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, it's not clear what you are seeking here. Please [Edit] this Question to contain a question. You should probably include details about how you obtained/generated the file, and an indication of the size and/or other way you validated the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Apologies for leaving out necessary information, I will edit it according to your recommendations.